# Compare method in list doesn't work(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Compare can't work in python.why?

```
a,b=10,20
print(cmp(a,b))
```

---

> ```
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-21-553f11ffcf97> in <module>()
>       1 import operator
>       2 a,b=10,20
> ----> 3 print(cmp(a,b))
>
> NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
> ```

Comment: I want to print output means 1 or -1 or 0

Comment: built-in `cmp` function has been removed that's why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmp() is excluded in python 3x built-ins, alternatively you can use

```
(a>b)-(a<b)
```

Comment: As per documentation this is official workaround of cmp in python3.

Comment: def cmp(a,b):
    return (a>b)-(a<b)
cmp(20,20)   finally i got it. Thank you!.